# Error in mysql query with python pymsql

Tags: python, mysql

I have an sql query error for the second sql inside this code: I know it's problem with escaping the single ' quote but i don't know how to it inside my params.. this is my first question

My second question is about the other kind of quote: ` ,I don't know why i need it around y field and table name, while i've seen on SO that all sql query don't need it. For info i use mysql server on localhost using easydevserver.

thanks in advance for your hints !

```
db = Database()
ea = Ean()

sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table 2` WHERE `categorie` = "Lego"'

listeproduit = db.select(sql)

for record in listeproduit:

    skuref     = "Mg "+ record[0][0:20]
    print (skuref)
    ean        = ea.generateEAN13CheckDigit()

lastpost = record[0]
lastean = ean
print(lastpost)
print (lastean


sql = """UPDATE `table 2` SET `ean`='%s' WHERE `nom`='%s'"""%(lastean,lastpost)
print (sql)
db.insert(sql)
```

Here is the output when i launch:

```
Lego Lego 79116 Tortues Ninja : L'évasion en camion
3700775101267
UPDATE `table 2` SET `ean`='3700775101267' WHERE `nom`='Lego Lego 79116 Tortues Ninja : L'évasion en camion'

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'évasion en camion'' at line 1")
```

In case you need more of my code, i use a class db like this:

```
class Database(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                                  user="root",         # your username
                                  passwd="",  # your password
                                  db="mgdeal",        # name of the data base
                                  charset='utf8',
                                  use_unicode=True,
                                  init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')


    def insert (self, sql):
        cursor= self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        newID = cursor.lastrowid
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return newID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quote with something like this : `str(lastpost).replace("'","\\'")`
It will tell mysql that it's a the quote is a part of the text.